# Rearranging a string value with delimiters in a sql select query

Tags: sql, select-query, regexp-substr

I have a column with string value having delimiters as shown below which I use  in the select part of sql query.

```
0040~0040~0040~0040~0040^00~00~00~01~05^100~001~010~011~015^00~00~00~01~05
```

individual heads are separated using `'^'` as shown below.

```
Head1 = 0040~0040~0040~0040~0040

Head2 = 00~00~00~01~05

Head3 = 100~001~010~011~015

Head4 = 00~00~00~01~05
```

all 4 heads have same number of  entries which are `'~'` delimited(entries not necessarily 5).

What I need is merge first entry from all 4 heads into one. As shown below.

`0040-00-100-00`  delimited by `'-'`

then for the second entry and so on for all the entries.

if the number of entries are 4 like my string, the formatted output should look like this(each entry separated by comma):

```
0040-00-100-00,0040-00-001-00,0040-00-010-00,0040-01-011-01,
0040-05-015-05
```

I want to do this in the select query where I fetch this column value.

example..

```
select x,y,z,(this is where I want this changes to be done.) from abc
```

Comment: Do your rows have an ID column?

Comment: yes. But that is not required for solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have presented is not one easily solved limiting yourself to the inside of a select statement.  Though you said that you didn't, if you knew how many "heads" there were going to be in each string, you could set up a single, complicated, and very long select statement (with your "string value having delimiters" called foobar):

```
SELECT x,y,z, SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '~') - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^') + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^')) - INSTR(foobar, '^') - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) - 1) || ',' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~') + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', 1, 2) - INSTR(foobar, '~', 1, 1) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1)) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2)) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3)) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) - 1) 
FROM abc
```

And that only gets the first two "entries", however it will get each "head", regardless of length and it can be extended to include more entries, but it would not work if there were only two entries and the select statement was extended for five entries, which is impractical since you said that a row may have any number of entries.  There is a way to achieve this using a `CASE` statement, but it is very long, and very complex.  Here is a sample query that may be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT x, y, z,
  CASE (LENGTH(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')))-LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')), '~', '')) + 1)
    WHEN 1 THEN SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^') - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) + 1, LENGTH(foobar) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3))
    WHEN 2 THEN SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '~') - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^') + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^')) - INSTR(foobar, '^') - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) - 1) || ',' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~') + 1, INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1) - INSTR(foobar, '~', 1, 1) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1)) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1), 1) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 1) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2)) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 2) - 1) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3)) + 1, INSTR(foobar, '~', INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3)) - INSTR(foobar, '^', 1, 3) - 1) 
    ELSE 'Too many entries: ' || (LENGTH(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')))-LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')), '~', '')) + 1) || ' entries given of 2 maximum'
  END AS SAMPLE_OUTPUT
FROM abc;
```

The query above (when extended beyond its current capacity of two entries) will organise your "heads".  It is very long and complex, but if you know the length of each head will be constant (such as always having a length of 4 per entry in "Head1"), then the code can be shortened, with the added benefit of faster execution, if the values are hard-coded in without `INSTR`.  The example below assumes that the head lengths are 4, 2, 3, and 2, as in your sample data:

```
SELECT x, y, z,
  CASE (LENGTH(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')))-LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')), '~', '')) + 1)
    WHEN 1 THEN REPLACE(foobar, '^', '-')
    WHEN 2 THEN SUBSTR(foobar, 1, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 11, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 17, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 25, 2) || ',' || SUBSTR(foobar, 6, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 14, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 21, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 28, 2) 
    WHEN 3 THEN SUBSTR(foobar, 1, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 16, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 25, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 37, 2) || ',' || SUBSTR(foobar, 6, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 19, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 29, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 40, 2) || ',' || SUBSTR(foobar, 11, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 22, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 33, 3) || '-' || SUBSTR(foobar, 43, 2)
    ELSE 'Too many entries: ' || (LENGTH(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')))-LENGTH(REPLACE(SUBSTR(foobar, 1, INSTR(foobar, '^')), '~', '')) + 1) || ' entries given of 3 maximum'
  END AS SAMPLE_OUTPUT
FROM abc;
```

One last note: I recommend using a column alias for the case statement for reasons that become very obvious should you attempt to test the code without one.

Comment: Yeah, this works fine if there are 2 entries. Since my entries length is not fixed, I will have to find another way to solve this..
Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @iamP The second query can be extended to accomodate more entries.  The example above only supports up to two entries, but more can be added.  If you want, I will extend the query to make it support more entries.

Comment: The entries can take any number. I guess it will be much more lengthy when the number goes 5+ or even 4+ . your code is quite easier to understand. Is there any way I can just iterate case 1 in some way for any number of entries , to make it short.?

Comment: @iamP If the lengths of the entries in each head is constant (like it is always 4 numbers as in "Head1"), then the query can be substantially shortened and would probably run faster because instead of including all the `INSTR` functions in the CASE statement, you could hard-code in values after determining the number of entries.  I will add an example of this to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First CTE is just a select to create dummy records, you can ignore that. 2nd CTE is recursive to split the column values on ^ per ID, 3rd CTE is to combine sections separated by `-` using XML per ID, last CTE is to combine all of them into a single string separated by `,`. Had to have an ID column to group by before combining everything. It'll work with n number of rows.

```
;WITH myTable (id, MyColumn)
AS (SELECT 1, '0040~0040~0040~0040^00~00~00~01~05^100~001~010~011~015^00~00~00~01~05'
union ALL SELECT 2, 'b040~0040~0040~0040^b0~00~00~01~05^b00~001~010~011~015^b02~00~00~01~05'
union ALL SELECT 3, 'c040~0040~0040~0040^c0~00~00~01~05^c00~001~010~011~015^c02~00~00~01~05'
union ALL SELECT 4, 'd040~0040~0040~0040^d0~00~00~01~05^d00~001~010~011~015^d02~00~00~01~05'
),
RecursiveCTE (id, sub, startInd, endInd)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        convert(varchar, SUBSTRING(MyColumn, 1, CHARINDEX('^', MyColumn ))) as sub
        , 0 AS startInd
        , CHARINDEX('^', MyColumn ) AS endInd
        from mytable
    UNION ALL
        select id,
        convert(varchar, SUBSTRING((SELECT MyColumn FROM myTable WHERE id = dr.id), endInd + 1, endInd - startInd)),
        endInd,
        CHARINDEX('^',  (SELECT MyColumn FROM myTable WHERE id = dr.id), endInd + 1) as endInd
    from RecursiveCTE dr
        where dr.endInd <> 0
),
PerIDSeperatedByDash AS (
select id,
STUFF((
select '-' + SUBSTRING(drinner.sub, 1, CHARINDEX('~', drinner.sub) - 1)
from RecursiveCTE drinner
WHERE (drinner.id = drouter.id)
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS DashSeperated
from RecursiveCTE drouter
group by id)
SELECT DISTINCT STUFF((
SELECT ',' + ds.DashSeperated
FROM PerIDSeperatedByDash ds
ORDER BY id
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') 
from PerIDSeperatedByDash
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I use it in the select format I have mentioned by just replacing last select parameter with your code some how?

Comment: @iamP I don't think you can use CTEs as inner selects. Why does it have to be in `select * from (query here) ` format?